# Using flexbox with 2 components but both are not adjacent

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, react-native

Image here.

[App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIL98.jpg)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kyc6b.jpg)

I just want Advice component close to Weather component.
How can I get it ?

App.js

```
<View style={styles.columnLayout}>
    <Weather currentCity="Phuket"/>
    <Advice />
  </View>
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
columnLayout : {
flex : 1,
flexDirection: 'column',
}
})
```

Weather and Advice component are not using flex.

WeatherData.js (export to Weather.js)

```
<View style={styles.viewStyle}>


            <View style={styles.dataStyle}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Temperature</Text>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{this.props.temp} °C</Text>

            </View>
            <View style={styles.dataStyle}>
                <Image style={{ width: 80, height: 80 }} source={{ uri: `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${this.props.icon}.png` }}></Image>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{this.props.description}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.dataStyle}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Humidity</Text>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{this.props.humidity} %</Text>
            </View>

        </View>
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
dataStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#00b377',
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"

},

viewStyle: {
    height: 150,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center"

},
textStyle: {
    color: 'white',
    textShadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
     textShadowOffset: {width: -1, height: 1},
     textShadowRadius: 10
}
```

})

another one Component using the same style.

Comment: Please copy and paste your code in your question. Debugging photos of code is unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: Edit your question and update the code in question itself rather a screenshot. Also share the code of Weather and view components

Comment: can you post styles for both components?

Comment: both components in App.js are not using flex just using margin and padding.

Comment: That code im added is enough for solve ? sorry this is my first topic :(

Answer (score 0):

I already add code. 
In react-native documents flex : 1 and flexDirection : column all View are adjacent
but mine is not.